# Start newline with auto-generated text in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am working on a file which has syntax similar to something like:

```
name=...
line=...
line=...
line=...
...
```

I would like to make it so that when I am currently on a line that starts with "line=" that when I press "Enter" it will move to the next line and auto-populate it with "line=". Is there a way to do this with an EventListener with a plugin or possibly a way to do it with a snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This key-binding will work:

```
{
    "keys": [ "enter" ],
    "command": "insert",
    "args": { "characters": "\nline=" },
    "context":
        [
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^line=", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match",    "operand": "$",      "match_all": true },
        ]
},
```

---

Additionally, you can add a `scope`-specific context by appending something like the following line into the `context` array:

```
{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python", "match_all": true },
```

---

See: [**Sublime Text > Unofficial Documentation > Key Bindings**](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/key_bindings.html) for more information on `context` parameters.

Comment: Yep perfect. I didn't know key bindings could have a context. Thanks so much!